# How does this statement work in C: a=a++?

Tags: c, variable-assignment, increment

```
int main()
{
    int a=0;
    a=a++;
    printf ("%d",a);
}
```

In this question, why does the value of `a` comes out to be 0 and not 1?

I mean, I understand that due to post-increment, the value assigned to `a` is 0. But then `a++` runs, so why doesn't the value of `a` becomes 1?

Comment: The real question is *when* does the `++` part run, and more importantly, *is that behaviour defined*. Another way to get to the bottom of "why" is to look at the assembly dump of the compiled output.

Comment: [Useful documentation on `++`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_incdec)

Comment: [Useful documentation on what happens when](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order) and what has no defined behaviour.

Comment: For this to work, you should just use a++, or use pre-increment: a=++a; Your approach is not working because it is storing a (let say, in a temporal variable t), incrementing a, and assigning t as the value of a. As you can see, the incremented value is never stored back into a.

Comment: *"why does the value of a comes out to be 0 and not 1"*  [Well..](https://godbolt.org/z/hYjs49)